# Converting the network identifier to text

Tags: network, history

In the cryptonote_config.h file, the network identifier is given as:

```
boost::uuids::uuid const NETWORK_ID = { {
      0x12 ,0x30, 0xF1, 0x71 , 0x61, 0x04 , 0x41, 0x61, 0x17, 0x31, 0x00, 0x82, 0x16, 0xA1, 0xA1, 0x10
    } }; // Bender's nightmare
```

I believe the comment means that this series of hex values should translate or convert into a string that reads "Bender's nightmare", but I'm not seeing how. Inputting the values into a site such as http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm I don't get that as my return string. So, how does the network identifier convert from hex values to ascii words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the numbers encode the phrase, but it must be a reference to Futurama.

In season 2 episode 7, Bender has a nightmare of random 1s and 0s appearing, and he thinks he even saw a 2! Whether our network identifier somehow relates with numbers appearing in that episode, I have no idea.

Comment: It may not, but if you search the source harder, you will find it elsewhere.